# Custom marked SVG polyline

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I have an SVG question. I have a polyline that should be marked like this:
[image]
 every N units. I have it drawn by four lines on top of one another, where top 3 are dashed to form squares.

The issue crops up when this line is not as straight as SVG likes it to be. While WPF handles this logic just fine
[image]
SVG is on meth
[image]
.

I kinda understand why it behaves weirdly and I am ready for "not so out-of-the-box" solution, but is there anything apart from calculating coordinates and angle for each square and drawing them separately?

Here is the code of SVG:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="1000" height="200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M390.79549408998 139.785864051271L390.79549408998 139.785864051271L436.31875178912 93.2509784032736L453.516426919901 110.448653534055L489.935033079208 67.9602796815307L504.097824363387 79.0881871190941L510.167592056605 66.9486517326586L519.272243596424 73.0184194258763L525.342011289642 60.8788840394409L535.458290778333 65.9370237837866L544.562942318167 49.7509766018775L555.690849755731 54.8091163462232L558.725733602347 45.7044648064038L573.900152835384 54.8091163462232L787.353650046876" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="7.0" stroke-dasharray="7, 35" stroke-dashoffset="0" />
        <path d="M390.79549408998 139.785864051271L390.79549408998 139.785864051271L436.31875178912 93.2509784032736L453.516426919901 110.448653534055L489.935033079208 67.9602796815307L504.097824363387 79.0881871190941L510.167592056605 66.9486517326586L519.272243596424 73.0184194258763L525.342011289642 60.8788840394409L535.458290778333 65.9370237837866L544.562942318167 49.7509766018775L555.690849755731 54.8091163462232L558.725733602347 45.7044648064038L573.900152835384 54.8091163462232L787.353650046876" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" />
        <path d="M390.79549408998 139.785864051271L390.79549408998 139.785864051271L436.31875178912 93.2509784032736L453.516426919901 110.448653534055L489.935033079208 67.9602796815307L504.097824363387 79.0881871190941L510.167592056605 66.9486517326586L519.272243596424 73.0184194258763L525.342011289642 60.8788840394409L535.458290778333 65.9370237837866L544.562942318167 49.7509766018775L555.690849755731 54.8091163462232L558.725733602347 45.7044648064038L573.900152835384 54.8091163462232L787.353650046876" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="5.0" stroke-dasharray="5, 37" stroke-dashoffset="-1" />
        <path d="M390.79549408998 139.785864051271L390.79549408998 139.785864051271L436.31875178912 93.2509784032736L453.516426919901 110.448653534055L489.935033079208 67.9602796815307L504.097824363387 79.0881871190941L510.167592056605 66.9486517326586L519.272243596424 73.0184194258763L525.342011289642 60.8788840394409L535.458290778333 65.9370237837866L544.562942318167 49.7509766018775L555.690849755731 54.8091163462232L558.725733602347 45.7044648064038L573.900152835384 54.8091163462232L787.353650046876" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2.0" stroke-dasharray="2, 40" stroke-dashoffset="-2.5" />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no built-infunctionality in SVG to enable what you want to do. The marker functionality in SVG allows you to define markers at the start, middle and end of a path, but not at X unit intervals.

You can either break your paths into smaller paths of x units and put a marker in the middle of them. Or you can manually draw the square markers afterward as separate shapes in the appropriate places.